# Multithreading reference?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, reference

I am asking about a good reference for multithreading programming in terms of concepts
with good examples using C++/C#?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Good reference for reading:
[Thread Management In The CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252943.aspx)
[Round-Robin Access To The ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347845.aspx)
[Multithreading with C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/udeshikah/002202009021606AM/0.aspx)
[Why are thread safe collections so hard?](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/11/why-are-thread-safe-collections-so-hard.aspx)
[Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)
[Jeffrey Richter’s Power Threading Library](http://www.wintellect.com/PowerThreading.aspx)
[Implementing a Thread-Safe Queue using Condition Variables](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html)
[Threading Building Blocks.org!](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)
[Sutter’s Mill - Effective Concurrency: Understanding Parallel Performance](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/effective-concurrency-understanding-parallel-performance/)
[Sutter’s Mill - Effective Concurrency: Use Threads Correctly = Isolation + Asynchronous Messages](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/effective-concurrency-use-threads-correctly-isolation-asynchronous-messages/)
[Thread Synchronization (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179(VS.80).aspx)
[How to synchronize access to a shared resource in a multithreading environment by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;816161)
[Use Threads Correctly = Isolation + Asynchronous Messages](http://www.ddj.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=215900465)
[Parallel and Multi-Core Computing with C/C++](http://www-949.ibm.com/software/rational/cafe/blogs/ccpp-parallel-multicore)
[Thinking in Concurrently in .NET](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2008/05/12/thinking-in-concurrently-in-net.aspx)
[Programming the Thread Pool in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx)
[Visual Basic .NET: Tracing, Logging, and Threading Made Easy with .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302019.aspx)
[Juice Up Your App with the Power of Hyper-Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300701.aspx)
[Concurrency Hazards - Solving 11 Likely Problems In Your Multithreaded Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc817398.aspx)
[INFO: Descriptions and Workings of OLE Threading Models - COM STA MTA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150777)
[C# Threading](http://tripous-net.com/CSharp_Theading.html)
[Thread Synchronization (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
[Overview of concurrency in .NET Framework 3.5](http://igoro.com/archive/overview-of-concurrency-in-net-framework-35/)
[Multi-threading in .NET: Introduction and suggestions](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/)
[Oracle - Multithreaded Programming Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1601/mtintro-75924.html)
[Multithreading Tutorial](http://www.computersciencelab.com/MultithreadingTut1.htm)
[64-Bit Programming with Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2k70f3s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[How to: Create and Terminate Threads (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

- [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916) with examples in Java (many can be rewritten in C++, but some get tricky due to garbage collection).
- [Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/reviews/patterns_for_parallel_programming_review.html)
- [Concurrency and Coordination Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/ccrdss/), [Parallel Framework Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/), [Microsoft concurrency page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/default.aspx) - different Microsoft approaches for .NET attempting to catch up Java with different high-level concurrency concepts (JSR166, JSR 166y)
- [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) (doesn't meet the criteria of C++/C#)
- [Partial Lock-Free data structures](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/srg/netos/lock-free/)
- [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/) - will cover multithreading from modern C++ point of view
- [Herb Sutter about concurrency](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/)
- C++0x proposals, for example [N2709](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2709.html), [N2744](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2744.html), etc.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [Joe Duffy](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Concurrent-Programming-Windows-Architecture-Development/dp/032143482X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1235981298&sr=8-1)'s new book on concurrency on Windows.  He covers both the Win32 API and the .NET framework.  Excellent reading.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Free threading book by Joseph Albahari..

PS: There are also Chinese, Czech, Persian, Russian translations on the site..

Answer (score 1):

I bought the vb.net version of this book [C# Threading Handbook (Paperback)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Threading-Handbook-Kourosh-Ardestani/dp/1861008295/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1235980688&sr=8-2) from amazon, which has all the reference i need.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN Library, while verbose, details most the information you'll need and has links to a bunch of tutorials - [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179(vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[The Little Book of Semaphores](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores/) is a free, online introductory textbook.  Example code is all in Python.