# System.Threading.Thread inheritance

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it possible to inherit from the Thread class and override the Start method?

Comment: Why do you want to? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd lay pretty good odds he just wants to pass one or more strongly-typed parameters to his method.

Comment: If he wants to pass a single strongly typed parameter, he should look into the ParameterizedThreadStartDelegate passed to the Thread ctor. This way he'd get a type safe Start overload.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think any inheritance could result in a more readable code than this:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    //Do what you want...
});
myThread.Start();
```

Comment: besides Thread is a Sealed class you can not inherit from Thread

Comment: With enough odd objects that I have to mess with and keep track of inside the thread, it certainly could.  I'm going to be writing a thread that has to dynamically load a DLL and call API methods on it while responding to requests coming in from the network.  I need more than just a method for my thread; I need a class.

Answer (score 22):

Regarding why someone would want to do this: a lot of languages (e.g. Java) and/or thread APIs (e.g. Qt) allow developers to implement threads by inheriting from a "thread" base class, and then overloading a method that implements the thread routine.

Having used this model extensively in Qt, I actually find it very handy--instead of having threads target some function or method, which often leads to weird and/or convoluted code, the whole thread is contained inside of an object.

Here's example code using the Qt API:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    void run();
};

void MyThread::run()
{
    ...something I need threaded...
}
```

QThread is Qt's threading base class.  To use MyThread, create an instance of the thread object and call QThread::start(). The code that appears in the run() reimplementation will then be executed in a separate thread.

What's nice about this is I think it lets you really contain everything a thread needs inside a single object, and (in my experience), it makes for a very coherent object model.  I don't think it meets everyone's needs, but I was a bit surprised that C# doesn't have such a basic threading model to be honest.

I definitely don't buy that C#'s Thread class is sealed because of kernel complexity; if Qt can supply a cross-platform threading library that allows inheritance of QThread, I see no real reason MSFT couldn't provide the same capability in a threading class in C#.

Comment: I agree with your response and have also used for many years that kind of abstract class in my C++ code.

Comment: The real reason is that they wanted a thin wrapper. :) Nothing stops anyone from creating a better wrapper around the official thin wrapper.

Answer (score 12):

```
using System.Threading;

namespace NGrubb.Threading {

    public abstract class BaseThread {
        private Thread m_thread;

        public BaseThread() {
            m_thread = new Thread( Run );
        }

        public void Start() {
            m_thread.Start();
        }

        protected abstract void Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't actually put a ThreadBase class like this into my codebase, but this makes a nice template to use.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

No, the `Thread` class is `sealed`. The rationale behind this decision is that it's such a tricky and low level wrapper around the kernel object that you should not mess with it.

One question for you though, why would you want to override the Start method? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ditto about why one would want to override Start.

Comment: I'd lay pretty good odds he just wants to pass one or more strongly-typed parameters to his method.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why you might want to do this (or that even should do this if it were possible), but there is a way to get around the fact that the `Thread` class is `sealed` - using extension methods. More technically, it's just adding an overload to the `Start` method group (rather than overriding), but that may still be helpful in your context.

Something like this might be what you want:

```
public static void Start(this Thread thread, int foo)
{
    // Your code here.

    thread.Start();
}
```

You can then simply call it as such:

```
var thread = new Thread();
thread.Start(123);
```

Answer (score 5):

The Thread class is sealed, but here's a [good site for learning about Threads](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). Also, take a look at the Stackoverflow thread here : [Multithreading reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601558/multithreading-reference)

Answer (score 2):

No...

The Thread class is sealed...

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public sealed class Thread : CriticalFinalizerObject, 
    _Thread
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No it is a sealed class which means you cannot inherit from it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also used to using the same logic in Java applications, and it makes serious sense to bundle a thread into an object which then further separates the start of a new process from its parent. Likewise, very disappointed C# does not support this approach. Dave P