# .net multithreading study material

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Can any one share some study material for multithreading on .net?

**EDIT:**  I don't want to learn too much details

Comment: lke "Multithreading reference" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601558/multithreading-reference/602001#602001

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend Joe Duffy's [Concurrent Programming On Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X). Also keep up with the [PFX team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/).

Comment: Great book if you want the gory details!

Comment: Joe Duffy's blog is a decent read too though it's not all concurrent stuff http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/Default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

From Joe Albahari's site

> ... An extensive article on [multithreading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). This tackles difficult issues such as  thread safety, when to use  Abort,  Wait Handles vs Wait and Pulse, the implications of  Apartment Threading in Windows Forms, using  Thread Pooling,  Synchronization Contexts, Memory Barriers and non-blocking  synchronization constructs.

Answer (score 3):

- [Jon Skeet has useful a guide](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/).
- There's also a free guide from the [C# in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) book
- Also, the new **3rd ed of C# via CLR** by Jeffrey Richter has been updated with several chapters on threading including coverage of Tasks, Parallel LINQ and so on.
- For in depth coverage of Windows threading check **Duffy**'s book as Jon suggests. It is really good.

Answer (score 3):

This [**one**](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) is very useful as on my opinion.

Comment: I am the first! :)) It is a good post, I know

Answer (score 1):

Google Search:

- http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx
- http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/threading-asp-net

...and a whole lot more.  Is there anything specific you are looking for?