# Creating Thread in Win32

Tags: winapi, multithreading

Does ThreadFunc() gets called two times here? sometimes I notice a single call and sometimes none at all.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID);

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD threadld;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, 0, 0, &threadld );
    printf("Thread is running\n");
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID p)
{
    printf("In ThreadFunc\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output 1**

```
Thread is running
In ThreadFunc
In ThreadFunc
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Output 2**

```
Thread is running
In ThreadFunc
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Output 3**

```
Thread is running
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601558/multithreading-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to call CRT functions, such as `printf` you should use [`_beginthread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [`_beginthreadex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.80%29.aspx) instead of `CreateThread`.

Anyway, the program may end before the thread has the opportunity to output anything.

Answer (score 2):

A little addition: use WaitForSingleObject inside main() to give your thread finish a job.

Answer (score 0):

No, ThreadFunc should never get called twice. In any case, I believe your code snippet is incomplete - could you post the full code snippet where you are seeing this problem?