# .net multi-threading

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'm writing dll which must run a function multiple times using different parameters, parallell to everything else.

I've tried the following methods:

- Backgroundworkers
- MethodInvoker
- Threads
- etc

What's the best way to do it?

**Update**:

I'm writing a dll, no GUI involved

Comment: many links here  : [Multithreading reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601558/multithreading-reference/602001#602001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.0, you should make use of the new [Parallel Task Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

If not, consider using the threadpool to do your work with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`.  Failing that, creating a new `Thread` object is the way to go.  Do **not** use `BackgroundWorker` for this; only if you were trying to decouple long-running processor-intensive code from blocking the UI would you use the `BackgroundWorker`.

There's a pretty good example of waiting for all the user workitems to complete here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx.  Essentially you pass a `ManualResetEvent` object into each call that is `Set()` when the async code completes.  You put all the `ManualResetEvent` objects in an array and call `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` passing in that array to wait for all the waithandles to be set.

Another technique could be to have a controlled number of `Thread` objects running that are waiting for items to appear in a `Queue`.  This is a fairly standard **Producer/Consumer** pattern that means you need less threads (and therefore resources) but can still decouple the request from the work by putting messages on a queue.  If you need the queue to be durable you could use MSMQ (and you can go even further than that with an ESB).

As you can see, *where* you are considering multi-threading makes a massive difference on *how* you implement it.  Windows Form multithreading would not be the same as a Windows Service's multithreading, and in turn neither would be the same as in an ASP.NET web application (where arguably threading isn't even a good idea due to resource management in IIS).  If you update your question we can be more specific to your current needs.

Comment: with pleasure, but, its 3.5 :(

Comment: ok, if i used pool, now i need to wait until all my threads finished, how it can be done?

Comment: Answer updated with an example and link.  Feel free to vote for people's answers if you find them helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Threading is tricky - which is "best" depends on the very specific scenario. For example, on a web server "best" may be not to use threading *at all*, and let other threads handle other requests. One thing you should avoid is saturating the `ThreadPool`, as other core parts of the system depend on that.

It *sounds* like a multiple-reader worker queue would serve your purposes; note also that .NET 4.0 introduces a range of controlls (around "Parallel" and "Tasks") that make threaded code easier to handle. A *reasonable* overview is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/_net_4_parallel.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

- If you are starting a background thread from a WinForms UI, use the BackgroundWorker component.
- If you don't particularly care when the job starts or finishes as long as it runs, use an asynchronous delegate or the thread pool.
- Otherwise, create a new thread manually.