# Resource for Win32 Multithreading

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, numerical-methods

I’m looking for a quick pointer to some multithreading resources for C/C++ on Win32.  I am interested in comparing the relative performance of numerical calculations using single and multiple threads.  The problems need not be real world but they shouldn’t be so trivial that relative performance is inconsequential.   My first attempt was to implement single threaded Sieve of Eratosthenes and Sieve of Atkin assuming there would be relatively simple multithreaded examples of both, but I haven’t been able locate any.
I don’t want to become a multithreading expert, but accept that this is going to take some effort, I’ve budgeted for around 30 hours of programming time.  I have copies of Windows Internals by Russinovich and Solomon and Windows via C/C++ by Richter and Nasarre, I am happy to purchase additional books but would prefer free resources if they exist.

I would like to avoid any external libraries e.g. Boost so as to keep the example as clean as possible to avoid any dependency issues. I don’t want to go any where near the CLR

The context is I write dlls/xlls for Excel, since Excel 12 Microsoft have claimed these functions can be multithreaded, I want to investigate how this works.

I've been off Stack Exchange for a year or two, so please be gentle.  I've had a bit of a hunt around most of the stuff I've found focuses on the theorectical rather than the implementation

Comment: Eratosphenes parallelizes trivially. The only problem you may have with it is the data memory cache, which is not quite related to threads per se. All thread-related APIs are described on MSDN and come with examples.

Comment: Are you using C++11 ? If yes you really don't need an external library as threads are integrated directly in the language.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies, looking at the Sieve of Eratosthenes, there appeared little to be gained by paralyzing the outer loop, but the inner loop could be split into odd even pairs but this would require locks on the true/false array which might dominate any performance gain from using 2 threads. Thinking about your answers attempting a multithreaded sieve would be a productive programming exercise even if it is not directly applicable to the problem I am trying to solve.

Also I forgot an important piece of information, I’m using Visual C++ 10 on XP version 5.1 service pack 3

Comment: @phineas are yoou looking for Knowledge about multi threading implementation or are you looking for algorithms that could be "parallelized"?

Comment: I know you don't really wish to use an external library but you might want to check out OpenMP anyway. Potentially you might be able to get away with simply adding a `#pragma omp parallel for` to your code.

Comment: [Multithreading reference help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601558/multithreading-reference/602001#602001)

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about multi threading calls in WinAPI could help here? Or do you need something more "tutorial like"?

For a step-in example see the MSDN article "[Creating Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" referenced by the documentation of the [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call.

Comment: What I was looking for was some code to cut and paste so I could step through to understand it, but given the answer and comments I think I’d benefit from working through the MSDN examples.

Comment: @phineas I just added a link to the MSDN article "Creating Threads". There you'll find example code and explainations. I hope that speeds up your research a bit :-)

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio you can activate OpenMP support, and it is then very easy to parallelize loops or regions of code. You can easily find tutorials, for an example [here](http://openmp.org/mp-documents/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf).

Comment: OpenMP is the easiest to use threading API. If your problem can be handled that way, then OpenMP is the way to go.